# Accepted Offer, What to do About Remaining Interview?

Tags: interviewing, professionalism, software-industry

I've accepted an offer recently, and have let most of the other companies know that I accepted.

However, there is one company that I've applied to many times over the years, which would be a dream to work at. They're well-known enough that I'm certain you have an app of theirs installed on your phone. This time, I was able to get a referral, greatly improving my chances--it paid off, and I was able to get at least a hiring screen booked in a few days.

The timing just didn't work out this time, and I don't plan on reneging the contract I've already signed.

However, I'm concerned that killing this interview process so soon (about 2-3 weeks since the application), especially after someone went out on a limb for me, will do more harm than good. I have a feeling that at least getting to a more advanced stage of the process before calling it quits will make it seem less like a waste of energy on their end (even though the *opposite* is true in reality), and may even make me seem more attractive as a candidate in the future.

So I'm asking:

- Should I end it now, saving everyone a great deal of time, but possibly burning a bridge?
- Or should I wait and see where it goes, possibly being in a greater position of power when rejecting them?

The recruiting team at this company has wasted my time a lot in the past, so I'm not terribly concerned about wasting an extra day or two of theirs if they don't know about it.

Comment: When you say you accepted an offer, did you see the contract yet? Do you know when your starting date is? Do you know what the benefits are? Do you know what your salary is going to be?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Yes to everything. It's a done deal. I start the next working day after this next interview.

Comment: "**Or should I wait and see where it goes, possibly being in a greater position of power when rejecting them?**"  What do you mean by "**position of power**" ?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 I have a (unfounded) suspicion that rejecting the offer after I've actually been vetted as acceptable will give me better odds when applying in some future application down the road, as opposed to just some generally unknown potential like any other. "This person we liked but turned us down" seems like better odds at nabbing the next interview than "they were like any other applicant and backed out."

Comment: @Eee, Hypothetically, if you complete the whole interview process with this "**DREAM**" company, and they offer you the job, will you take it or will you still reject it (and still keep the original offer from the first company) ?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 No. I think it would be too big a blow to my reputation (and conscience) to be at the new job for two weeks, only to jump ship for my own personal gain.

Comment: And you have not actually stated the new job, and you might roll in and find drastic problems.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No one is going to consider it a burned bridge if you email them and let them know that you have to cancel the interview because you accepted another offer.  That happens all the time.  Anyone involved in hiring knows that good candidates aren't going to be on the market long.  They expect that people will pull out because they got an offer from someone else.

Save everyone the time and energy and pull out now.  Your dream company won't hold it against you.  In the unlikely event that someone even remembers it the next time you're in the market, they'll likely remember you were a promising candidate that someone else offered first.

If you do move to a later round, the conversation likely only gets more awkward.  Dream Co fully understands that they're not going to be able to complete the interview process and get you an offer before the offer you have in your hand has to be accepted.  If you've gone through a couple rounds of interviews, though, they could move relatively quickly if they need to match another offer.  So then you'd be in a position of telling them that you'd rather work at Existing Offer rather than Dream Co if they match the offer (or reneging on the offer you accepted/ resigning a few days into the new job) which would be much more likely to create a negative impression.

Comment: Thank you, this was indispensable advice. I've since turned them down.

Comment: Totally agree with this answer.  Telling your "dream employer" that they weren't fast enough to get a talented hire only increases your desirability in the future!  Use this as an opportunity to build a contact with them; stay in touch with them, and let them remember you as "the one that got away".   P.S. @JustinCave : Did we go to school together?

Comment: @abelenky - Small world-- you were at Random?

Comment: Yup!   Small world.  Nice to see you.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to give a different answer:

If it is a dream job and with a Marquee company,  then I would attend the interview.

For 2 reasons:

1: At the very least, it will give you experience of what it is like to interview with such a prominent company, the experience gained, even from an interview is likely to be worthwhile.

2: You may get an offer and it may be good enough that you don't proceed with the other offer.

Answer (score 1):

I would have gone to the interview. If it really is your dream company, you might just change your mind about the first offer. After all, signing a contract is somewhat a long term commitment.

In the Netherlands there is a clause in contracts (At least all the ones I have signed) that says you can be fired in the first month without any explanation. The companies do not like it, but it does go both ways, meaning one can also leave in the first month without an explanation. I had already signed a contract once, but then my 'dream company', who was taking very long, came back with a much better offer. Since my contract stipulated I can leave without any reason, that is what I did. Of course, there were hard feelings and I probably will never work at the former company, but it was 100% worth it.

The company will do what is best for them, so you have to do what is best for you. And working at your dream company might be it.